# Как лучше отрисовывать анимацию в Android?

Tags: android, opengl, graphics

На работе мне дали задание сделать анимацию похожу на [Siri Wave](https://github.com/caffeinalab/siriwavejs), но я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при рисовании стандартными средствами типа `drawLine()`, у меня начинает проседать FPS (при использовании `Path.quadTo()` все ещё хуже). Обуславливается это тем, что для плавности анимации часто происходит пересчет значений, а с каждым пересчетом - перерисовка.

Я пока новичок в Android-разработке и не знаком с какими-то другими средствами для анимированной отрисовки в Android. Знаю что можно использовать OpenGL, но не знаю стоит ли его использовать вот в таких ситуациях.

Хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов по этой ситуации. Что делать, что использовать, мб есть какие-то средства для оптимизации процесса отрисовки?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/)